# Erase content in the range basing on condition - match with defined name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run the code that will erase the lines in specific ranges if the ID in the first column of the range matches the defined name with the first characters (i.e. if the ID has more characters but it matches the first characters of the defined name - the row content should be erased )

I would like to that for multiple ranges but for now, I am trying on one range cuz it doesn't come right.

Here is how it looks before running the code:

[image]

Here is outcome:
[image]

My code looks like that, but I am getting an message error and I didn't include the 2nd range as I wanted to try with the first one.

```
Sub Erase()
Dim r As Long
Dim endRow As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet

Const ColumnStart1 As Integer = 2
Const ColumnEnd1 As Integer = 5

Const ColumnStart2 As Integer = 7   'to add
Const ColumnEnd2 As Integer = 10    ' to add

Const ColumnStart3 As Integer = 12   'to add
Const ColumnEnd3 As Integer = 15     'to add


Const l_MyDefinedName As String = "ID"
Dim ColumnNo As Integer
Dim ClearingRange As Range



Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


With TargetSheet

StartRow = 8
Dim lngLastRow As Long
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColumnStart1).End(xlUp).Row   '
        Set ClearingRange = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, ColumnStart1), .Cells(lngLastRow, ColumnEnd1))

Dim ID As String

      ID = ThisWorkbook.Names(l_MyDefinedName).RefersToRange.Value


    With IDRange
        Dim MachID As String


        For StartRow = 15 To ClearingRange.Rows.Count

             MatchID = Left(.Cells(StartRow, ColumnStart1), ColumnStart1)

            If MatchID = ID Then

            For ColumnNo = ColumnStart1 To ColumnEnd1
'

                 '*********Clear what is inside********'

        TargetSheet.Cells(StartRow, ColumnNo).ClearContent



            Next ColumnNo

        StartRow = StartRow + 1

            End If
Next StartRow
End With
End With


End Sub
```

Could anybody give a hand on that?

Comment: What is the specific problem you want solved for this question? Make it one issue if possible. If it is the error please state what the error is and on what line it occurs. It would also help to see the desired outcome aswell as the actual.

Comment: I have attached 2 pictures; first picture before running the code, and the other of my  desired outome. The error I am getting is: 'Runt-time error '424': Object required' . Debug sets on:  MatchID = Left(.Cells(StartRow, ColumnStart1), ColumnStart1)

Comment: First two things 1) Put Option Explicit at the top of your modue **and** 2) absolutely change the name of your sub from Erase to something less potentially problematic and more descriptive. Additional, change Integer to Long.

Comment: Then at the error point what are the values of StartRow and ColumnStart1 ?

Comment: I have corrected the sub name, added Option explicit, and changed integer to long. I have also corrected 'IDRange' to 'ClearingRange' as it was supposed to be. Debug still sets on  MatchID = Left(.Cells(StartRow, ColumnStart1), ColumnStart1) but I can't see the values at error point because now the error is 'Compile error: Variable not defined'

Comment: In which line? It means something isn’t declared and it should be shown on the line where the error occurs.

Comment: StartRow shows: 'Local StartRow as Long',  and ColumnStart1 shows: '2'  as it should. StartRow on the other hand is not showing as it shoud

Comment: On the line where debug sets i.e. MatchID = Left(.Cells(StartRow, ColumnStart1), ColumnStart1)

Comment: Ok, I found why error was showing up 'MatchID' was wrongly declared (misspelled). Now I have corrected that and code runs without error but nothing is happening - no desired outcome :/

Comment: you beat me to it. I was just about to say spelling! That is the advantage of Option Explicit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170561/discussion-between-qharr-and-dozens).